# Update MySQL table with foreach passing multiple list values

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm actually running into an issue when trying to put this into practice. So, I have a list of goal ids and a current amount. I need to pass all these values which I am by doing goalidlist[] and current[]. The issue is when I'm running the foreach and doing the SQL Update per goalid. Here's my code below. Hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$goalidlist = $_POST['goalidlist'];
$currentnums = $_POST['current'];
if (isset($_POST['goalidlist'])) {

    foreach($goalidlist as $key => $glist) {
        
        // Update key goals
        $updGoals = "UPDATE okr_3519031jkl.key_goals SET current=? WHERE goalid=? AND userid=?";
        
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $updGoals)) {
            // Bind Params
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sii", $currentnums[$key], $glist, $userid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $stmt->close();

            
        }
    }
}
```

**goalidlist[]** = Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 9 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 )

**current[]** = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 6 [4] => 2 [5] => 12 [6] => 3 [7] => 1 [8] => 7 [9] => 9 [10] => 2 [11] => 6 [12] => 3 )

Comment: What the problem here? Is "goalidlist" are array (passing data is exist)? You need to check the "goalidlist" using `var_dump` / `print_r` first

Comment: Oh have checked and both are populated as they should. So, the data is there. But for some reason it won't perform the update. That foreach should look at every item in goalidlist[]  and every number in current[] according to the code above but nothing get's updated.

Comment: Please, add to your question var_dump() result for goalidlist, currentnums and userid before entering the loop. Also, are you sure that in the table there are rows with goalid and userid you are searching for?

Comment: You can debug using `echo "attempt number " . $loop++ . "\n"` to see if your query is executed inside `mysqli_prepare`

Comment: that gave me this output attempt number 0 attempt number 1 attempt number 2 attempt number 3 attempt number 4 attempt number 5 attempt number 6 attempt number 7 attempt number 8 attempt number 9 attempt number 10 attempt number 11 attempt number 12

Comment: I also don't see anything within the server logs, and mysqli does not return any errors either.